# Is the current 1.6.0 version of MooTools compatible with older versions?

Tags: mootools

I'm upgrading from MooTools 1.3 to the newest 1.6.0, but when I do the date picker on my site disappears. I tried all the old compat versions of MooTools between 1.3 and 1.6.0 (1.4.5, 1.5.1 and 1.5.2) and they don't break the date picker, but as soon as I try and use the latest 1.6.0 the date picker breaks.

Is the newest version 1.6.0 compatible with older versions?

I was downloading from here: https://mootools.net/core

Answer (score 2):

I found that I could customise my download here: https://mootools.net/core/builder

From there I could choose an option to download 1.6.0 with a compat layer, and that solved my issue.